# How to customise Kendo Scheduler Week View?

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, scheduler

I need to customize view of Kendo Scheduler Week View to display same as below
[image]

I want to display bigger boxes of days and display all my appointment over there. can any one help me.

I have also checked Kendo documentation but nothing found which will help to change the week view HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating custom view by extending the build-in one and override the methods responsible for the rendering. Similar example is available in the Knedo UI CodeLibrary:

- [Scheduler: Custom view](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-view-329353883750)
- [Scheduler: Custom view with custom date range and swipe support](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/view-with-custom-date-range-and-swipe-support)